# How can I return a formatted string from a REST call?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

How can I create a Restful web service that will display as a multi line result in a Windows console.

I have tried the following but it displays the \r\n as string characters instead of line feeds. Also tried just \n, 0x0A, nothing seems to work.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fetchMultiLine.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String fetchMultiLine(HttpServletRequest request) {
   return "Lines:\r\nfirst\r\nsecond\r\netc"
}
```

It always interprets the new line character as string characters and displays:

```
Lines:\r\nfirst\r\nsecond\r\netc
```

When I really want

```
Lines:
first
second
etc
```

Any hope?

Comment: what about a List<String> where each item in the list is a line

Comment: No, ["Failed!","Error message:Nice try but no cigar", "Try again"]